# Parskip: Suppressing parskip in some places

Tags: parskip

I use the package `parskip`, but want to suppress the parskip in some places, i.e. after headings inserted by a specific macro.

A negative `vspace` doesn't work, since `parskip`'s spacing can stretch.

The only workaround I found is using `\\` instead of a paragraph, but that feels wrong. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
foo\par bar\par baz

{\parskip=0pt
foo\par bar\par baz\par}

foo\par bar\par baz
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or as a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\par#1\par\vspace{-\parskip}}
\begin{document}
bar\par bar

\foo{some nonsense}

bar\par bar

\foo{some nonsense}

bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good, thanks. Can I use that to define a macro `\foo` that prints a paragraph `foo` _after_ which there is no parskip? The obvious `{\parskip=0pt foo\par}` doesn't work, since the parskip as applied where a paragraph begins, not where it ends.

Comment: see my edited answer