# Emulate tabular vertical spacing with parskip package

Tags: tables, spacing, parskip

I would like to emulate the vertical spacing of `tabular` without using `tabular`. When the `\parskip` package is used,  using `\par` leaves too much vertical space, so I thought I'd emulate it with use of a `\newline`:

[image]

Now, this seems to work just fine, most of the time. But am running into a *Missing number, treated as zero* which I suspect is related to using a `\newline`. Plus I recall something about using a `\\` or `\newline` outside of a `tabular` or `array` type of environment being a *bad* thing.

So, my question is: Is using `\\` or `\newline` a *bad* thing, and if so, why? What alternative ways can I emulate the vertical spacing of `tabular` when using the `parskip` package?

### References

- [Parskip: Suppressing parskip in some places](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112312/parskip-suppressing-parskip-in-some-places) suggest to adjust `parskip`, but this is considered a "deadly sin" as per [Too much whitespace before lists when changing the \parskip length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14764/too-much-whitespace-before-lists-when-changing-the-parskip-length)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand{\ColumnA}[2][l]{\makebox[2.5em][#1]{#2}}%

\begin{document}
Output using \verb|tabular|:

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
abc & def \\
uvw & xyz \\
\end{tabular}

Using \verb|\par| leaves additional vertical space:

\ColumnA{abc}  def \par
\ColumnA{uvw}  xyz \par

\medskip
Emulating \verb|tabular|:

\ColumnA{abc}  def \newline
\ColumnA{uvw}  xyz \newline

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm confused: parskip (more or less) just increases \parskip to put space between paragraphs, if you don't want paragraphs with space between don't use it (or locally set \parskip back to zero?

Comment: I cannot see why  the double backslash schouldn't be used in your case?? It is only a problem inside a paragraph with more than one line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am ok with setting `\parskip` locally, just thought that that it was recommended int the linked questions to _not_ do that.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks. I will use the double backslash then.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Herbert you should use `\\`. It is *no* bad thing. If you really want to end a line, it is the right thing for you. In most cases it should be also your preferred way of breaking lines, because some environments redefine `\\` to suit the current formatting.

If you search for something stretching your text to line end you should have a look at `\linebreak`.

My suggestion regarding `parskip`: Forget it. You don't need it. You want content which is not in distinct paragraphs, so linebreaks are sufficient.